# Objective C: "_main", referenced from: Start in crt1.3.1.o error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Trying to compile a iPhone/iPad application with SDK3.2 and am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
"_main", referenced from:
Start in crt1.10.5.o
Symbol(s) not found
Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

I think it's telling me that it's somehow trying to work with code from another SDK but searching the web has not provided any clear answers.

Anyone able to guide me on this and what to look for?

Comment: are you using eclipse or Xcode....?

Comment: I'm using XCode. I just noticed that I'm getting two different crt references as well. Definitely picking up another SDK somehow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *looks* like you haven't provided a `main` function in any of your source files. The `crt` object file is most likely the startup code which sets up your environment then calls `main` (CRT usually stands for C runtime, when it's not being used to mean Cathode Ray Tube, which it shouldn't any more, that being dead technology and all).

The `Undefined symbols: "_main" ...` simply means that the linker has discovered `crt1.10.5.o` needs the `_main` symbol satisfied and none of the files provided are satisfying it.

Short of seeing the actual linker command line, we can't be certain what's being included. You should check your source code and confirm or deny the existence of `main()`? And that it's inluded in the build?

Comment: Doh! I was thinking I had a main function being included when it wasn't. Thanks. So obvious :-)

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be several possible causes.

I ran into this problem when the **Perform Single-Object Prelink** build option was checked 
(GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE = YES).

Comment: I was getting an error for _main undefined in Arm64 architecture in my release build. Setting the **Perform Single-Object Prelink** to "No" is what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I opened a Swift project in Xcode 5.  When I opened it in Xcode 6, it worked fine.